# Convert & Save Webm Video File to Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am recording an video using WebRTC. And successfully created a Webm format video. But now I am stuck at a situation where I have to upload the Webm video to my online server.

Ajax Code I am using:

```
function UploadToServer(blob) { 
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('video-blob', blob);
formData.append('video-filename', 'FileName.webm');
$.ajax({
    url: "testpost.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        alert('Error:' + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
    }
});
}
```

PHP Code:

```
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

    echo 'uploads/';

    $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
    $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
        echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
    }

    echo($fileName);
}
}
```

blob in function is like this: blob:https://www.xyxz.com/asd45a4s5454-asdsa-asd-asd-as-das-da-sdasd-548485

Everything is fine just unable to upload this Webm video to Server using PHP and AJAX.